# When do we use nested modules and nested classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I came across two files which had a structure like this. What are some practical examples in which I will create File A to execute some code, and similarly when would the structure of File B be more useful ? I take it that the answer lies somewhere in reusability and name spacing ?, but I am not able to give myself a clear answer as to what the difference between these two are.

file_a.rb

```rb
module A
  module B
   // Code runs here
  end
end
```

file_b.rb

```rb
module A
  class B
   // Code runs here
  end
end
```

Comment: "when do you use a class vs a module" and "when do you nest" are completely orthogonal questions, btw

Comment: When do you nest for name-spacing purposes, is there any advantage of one over the other ?

Comment: Ruby doesn't have nested modules or nested classes. It is not the modules that are nesting, it is the constants.

Comment: You probably should read, if you haven't yet, the [autoloading section of the Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html) because this question is actually kinda different if we're talking about vanilla Ruby and if we're talking about Ruby on Rails. In vanilla Ruby it's basically what @Jörg W Mittag said in the comment above mine. In Rails, well, it's not truly different, since it's still Ruby, but Rails does a looot of magic behind the scenes in a way that the choice between the two may become much more relevant.